# Cannot get gcov to produce any coverage data

Tags: c, gcc, gcov

Failing to get gcov coverage file with my C/C++ Makefile project with  googletest on Windows with mingw32 
Full source code at https://github.com/rusefi/rusefi/tree/gcov/unit_tests

I have

````
USE_OPT += -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage
ULIBS += -lgcov --coverage```
````

and I get .gcno files next to my .o files in build\obj folder

I execute rusefi_test.exe and I see no new files with coverage data :(

```
nm rusefi_test.exe
```

confirms that gcov is inside my binary

I've already added explicit flush at the end

```
extern "C" void __gcov_flush();
__gcov_flush();
```

but I still do not see any

```
90.00% of 10 source lines executed in file tmp.c
```

style line at the end of stdout

I've tried copying my .exe from build to build\obj folder but this did not improve anything.

Comment: Yes, I have read the manpage but I am probably missing something. Do you have any ideas what I could be missing?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like my compiler has something to do with this! I've moved to a simple HelloWorld.cpp application and depending on compiler I either get runtime file or not!

main.exe produced by "g++" from cygwin produces the runtime file while x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ from cygwin does NOT produce main.gcda file!

x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ bundled with cygwin seems to be affected while same x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ downloaded directly from mingw64 seems to work.

There is https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=854368 which they say is closed but at least tells me that sometimes it's about the compiler itself :(